# Unable to find numpy when installing external package in read-the-doc build

Tags: python, numpy, github, read-the-docs

I'm trying to use an external package `somoclu` for my project and have included it in `requirements.txt`, but `readthedocs` raises an error when trying to build:

```
Collecting numpy
  Downloading numpy-1.23.3-cp39-cp39-manylinux_2_17_x86_64.manylinux2014_x86_64.whl (17.1 MB)
     ━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━ 17.1/17.1 MB 77.3 MB/s eta 0:00:00
Requirement already satisfied: sphinx in /home/docs/checkouts/readthedocs.org/user_builds/my/project/lib/python3.9/site-packages (from -r docs/requirements.txt (line 5)) (5.2.2)
...
Collecting somoclu
  Downloading somoclu-1.7.5.1.tar.gz (6.1 MB)
     ━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━ 6.1/6.1 MB 154.0 MB/s eta 0:00:00
  Preparing metadata (setup.py): started
  Preparing metadata (setup.py): finished with status 'error'
  error: subprocess-exited-with-error
  
  × python setup.py egg_info did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1
  ╰─> [6 lines of output]
      Traceback (most recent call last):
        File "<string>", line 2, in <module>
        File "<pip-setuptools-caller>", line 34, in <module>
        File "/tmp/pip-install-yjrktktm/somoclu_f38134a40b7747e6a0372e4bc55abcef/setup.py", line 4, in <module>
          import numpy
      ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'numpy'
      [end of output]
  
  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
error: metadata-generation-failed
```

It seems that the `setup.py` file in `somoclu` needs to import `numpy`, but I'm confused since `numpy` is explicitly included in `requirements.txt`, and the build also installed `numpy` before `somoclu` (please see the error message above). How can I resolve this issue?

Comment: Check your log file on RTD for errors.

Comment: What's your Read the Docs project's URL?